# Android Proguard build failed: Duplicated zip entry

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm getting this error while assemble release:

> Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/tuanchauict/pw/Android/xrmovies/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/prod/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read [/Users/tuanchauict/pw/Android/xrmovies/app/build/intermediates/classes/prod/release(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v7/a/a$a.class == android/support/v7/appcompat/R$attr.class]))
>   :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProdRelease FAILED

This is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/tuanchauict/pw/Android/xrmovies/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/prod/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read [/Users/tuanchauict/pw/Android/xrmovies/app/build/intermediates/classes/prod/release(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v7/a/a$a.class == android/support/v7/appcompat/R$attr.class]))
        at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:187)
        at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:79)
        at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:427)
        at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:175)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:54)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:254)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:63)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:173)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:49)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:223)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [/Users/tuanchauict/pw/Android/xrmovies/app/build/intermediates/classes/prod/release(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v7/a/a$a.class == android/support/v7/appcompat/R$attr.class])
        at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:188)
        at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:158)
        at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:176)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v7/a/a$a.class == android/support/v7/appcompat/R$attr.class]
        at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:138)
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:105)
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:105)
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
        at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
        at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
        at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:74)
        at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:74)
        at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:74)
        at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:74)
        at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:74)
        at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
        at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
        ... 12 more


BUILD FAILED
```

I have searched around but no solution this case.

My dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
```

Comment: without proguard all goes well?

Comment: Yeah, I can run in debug mode

Comment: how do you removed it? post your solution for future users :)

Comment: Actually, I grabbed its code into my app instead of using the gradle dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I have figured out where the problem came from. I use a 3rd party library that somehow it included the R class from support library. Remove it out and the build works.